# How can I add group account to Microsoft Teams?

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

When Team member changes, How can I change team members in Microsoft Teams automatically?
Should I manually add new team members to the team?
Can I just add group account such as team@xxx.com to the Microsoft Teams? so ever since team member changes, I don't have to add manually team members to the new chats.

Answer (score 0):

Bots in Teams get a `conversationUpdate` message when team members are added and removed, and if your goal is to be able to message users by their id, you can act on these events to ensure your cached roster is up to date.  Similarly you can fetch the roster of the team at any point to get the list of users.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/botevents